# trim a string ending with a specific character

Tags: javascript, string

for example, I have a variable (var1) with a value of `'root'@'localhost'` what's the best way to transform this variable to only `root` ?

I have tried:

```
slice(1, var1.length - 13)
```

But I figure it's not practical since var1 can have a value of `'root'@'%'` so what I think I should do is slice the first character "`'`" and trim the string starting from the 2nd "`'`" so I could get the user name.

Or is there any better way to do it?

Comment: where do you know, that it contains `'root'`?

Comment: `str.split('@')[0]`

Comment: Use Regex **(root)**

Comment: I don't see any difference b/w two strings however you can use the index of function to get the index of @ and then slice from 0 to that index - 1

Comment: @EgorEgorov’s suggestion fits nicely here, but in a case where you actually need to find the first occurrence of character in a string, there’s always `indexOf`

Comment: @Nina Scholz - i get the data from a table in mysql

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/as8hVi/2 try Regex (root)

Comment: Try: `"'root'@'localhost'".split("@")[0].replace(/'/g, "")`

Comment: @EgorEgorov great nearly does the job, however it resulted to 'root' need to remove the quotation marks as well. Any additional way to remove it?

Comment: If you have single quotes as well in the value then you can do str.split('@')[0].substr(1).slice(0, -1);

Comment: you can add `.slice(1,-1)` to remove the quotation marks

Answer (score -1):

In your case you can do something as follows

```
var x = "'root'@admin.com'";  
var y = x.split('@')[0].substr(1).slice(0, -1); 
console.log(y); // output: root
```

Following is the working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/w5Lhou6m/